# Removing empty rows of combobox in excel - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

This code show all cells column **A** of **Sheet1** (*Even empty values in end*).
What is the solution to Display up to the ***last row*** has a ***value*** in **combobox1** (*and remove empaty values in end*)?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ComboBox1.List = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    ComboBox1.List = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
End With
```

Comment: Hi and Thank you. You left the word "End With"

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With Sheets("Sheet1")
  ComboBox1.List = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp)).Value
End With
End Sub
```